# traverse through unique id to get children

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If my tree looks like that:

```
{
unique_id_1: {
    message: "hello"
    }
unique_id_2: {
    message: "hi there"
    }
}
```

How do I get all messages that are children of each unique id if I don't know the user's unique id? Or I have to build my database so that a message can only be a direct child of a unique id and then traverse like so:

```
DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference reference = database.child("message");
```

Or that would not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get all the messages, you need to loop:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
     String messages = datas.child("message").getValue().toString();
     }
 }
@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
     }
});
```

Here the datasnapshot is at the root node then if you have unique ids and don't have there values, you can just loop inside these unique ids `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` and get the messages.

You can also retrieve the unique ids by doing `String key = datas.getKey();`

Comment: So for that to work, I must only have "message" key when refering to message of the unique id, i can't have another "message" because I'll get un wanted results, right?
Thanks

Comment: This will retrieve all the "message" under a unique Id. If you want to add another attribute you should call it "messages", I dnt think you can use the same attribute name under the same key.. If that's what you mean